# adding users to group in IBM Directory server (LDAP)

Tags: ldap

Can some one tell me how to add users to group using ldif file?
what should be in the ldif file
for example 
cn=group1,ou=Groups,dc=mydom,dc=com
changetype: modify
what else?

Thanks
Borna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on objectclass you're using for group. If it's *groupOfNames*, LDIF file would be:

```
dn: cn=group1,ou=Groups,dc=mydom,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: member
member: *DN_you_want_to_add_goes_here*
```

Comment: Thanks, the objectclass is groupOfnames. So I should use full DN instead of just userid? something like this member: uid=user1,cn=users,....,dc=mydom,dc=com instead of just member: user1

Comment: From [this](https://www.ldap.com/ldap-dns-and-rdns), DN is **DN is much like an absolute path on a filesystem, ...**, so of course it have to be full path.